# F# Using Pose to Shim printfn for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, f#

I'm trying to use Pose (https://github.com/tonerdo/pose) to shim out `printfn` so I can unit test what is passed to it. I've managed to get it working if I'm passing a `TextWriterFormat` that doesn't take additional arguments, but when I  try to shim one that does take additional arguments I get a Mismatched instance types exception

This works:

```
let workingPrintfTest () =
    let a = Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>("herp")
    Printf.printfn a

let workingShim =
    Shim
        .Replace(fun () ->
            Printf.printfn(Is.A<Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>>())
        )
        .With(Func<Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>, unit>(fun s ->
            Console.WriteLine("Hijacked: " + s.ToString())
        ))

    PoseContext.Isolate ((fun () ->
        Program.workingPrintfTest ()   // Hijacked: herp
    ), workingShim)
```

However, when I change `herp` to `herp: %s` and the `TextWriterFormat` becomes `TextWriterFormat<string -> unit>` is when I get the mismatched instance types exception.

This throws exception:

```
let printfTest toPrint =
    let a = Printf.TextWriterFormat<string -> unit>("herp: %s")
    Printf.printfn a toPrint

let shim =
    Shim
        .Replace(fun () ->
            let a = Is.A<Printf.TextWriterFormat<string -> unit>>()
            Printf.printfn a (Is.A<string>())
        )
        .With(Func<Printf.TextWriterFormat<string -> unit>, unit>(fun s ->
                Console.WriteLine("Hijacked: " + s.ToString())
                ()
            )
        )

PoseContext.Isolate ((fun () ->
    Program.printfTest "www"
), shim)
```

And the accompanying Exception: `Pose.Exceptions.InvalidShimSignatureException: Mismatched instance types`

I'm running this in .Net Core 2.2

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because `printfn` is not a function with multiple parameters, as seen from .NET land. It's a function with one parameter that returns another function.

Comment: But I thought that `Printf.printfn a` is a partially applied function that then only requires one parameter?

Comment: A tip would be to check what the IL code the F# code is generates. There are numerous tools in .NET that allows you to inspect and disassemble IL code. That way you can maybe find the proper signature.

Comment: Hmmm. Looking at this, https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA9gBwKYDsAEBlAnhAC7oC2AsAFBWnIwCuw62AhtgLxXbfZNHYB3ZACcA1gEtMAcwAKwyUTAAVdMWwAKAJQcuPPX1YdschWAB0KgB5EA6vJLCAYiNIsiAHnqZxRAHzqAIgALdGFUAM1dPW4TTEUzVHk4sBwWKijedH5E0xU1ImRY/k5KaJ4DNnZjJPirW3tQ52FXD2IkqWwAWl9sLx9/YNDUEGwAUggIjL0i8xzk1KogA The second version seems to compile to something much more complicated than I thought.